# Maven, can I force a dependency to use a specific dependency

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services

I've recently upgraded com.amazonaws to version 1.11.xxx.
From version 1.11.0 onwards amazon dropped support for com.amazonaws.util.json in favour of Jackson.

One of my dependencies (over which I have no control), imports
com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONException

This is causing a NoClassDefFoundError for JSONException

Is there a way to configure maven so that this dependency can continue to use an older version of com.amazonaws so that it can find this class?

Note, I've not added an exclusion for amazonaws to the dependency in question, however it seems that the fact that I've upgraded the version in my pom is overriding the dependency's older version.

Comment: To fix that exception you'd probably need to load 2 versions of `com.amazonaws` at runtime - and doing that is a receipe for disaster. If you can't upgrade you might have to split your application or use different classloaders along with a suitable classloader hierarchy (easy to get wrong).

Comment: You might be able to use the maven-shade-plugin or the maven-assembly-plugin to build an artifact out of just the missing classes, so you don't end up with multiple versions of the same classes on your classpath (see Thomas' comment about recipe for disaster). Whether or not that's a good idea depends on what classes are involved. If it's just an exception or two might get you past the problem until the other library catches up.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find anything and was hoping there was a non-ugly option.